# Windows 8 C# Save ScrollerViewer state on Frame.Navigate

Tags: c#, windows-8, scrollviewer

I need to save the position of my ScrollViewer so that when I navigate to a page and hit the back arrow, it will still be at the position it was.

I'm using:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            base.LoadState(navigationParameter, pageState);
            if (pageState != null && pageState.ContainsKey("ScrollerPosition"))
            {
                mainScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double) pageState["ScrollerPosition"]);
            }
        }
```

and

```
protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            base.SaveState(pageState);
            pageState["ScrollerPosition"] = mainScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
        }
```

but it isn't restoring the state it was at. What am I doing wrong? (I'm very new to Windows 8!)

Answer (score 0):

The issue *might* be that `LoadState` is called prior to any of your data being loaded. If that is the case, there is no content to scroll so your `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` call has no effect.

You don't have any detail on how you load your data, so I cannot make a specific recommendation.  However, the general solution is to make sure all of your data is loaded prior to your call to set the scroll position.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up setting the NavigationCacheMode="Enabled" in the layoutawarepage and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The place to restore your scroll viewer is in the Loaded event. Add a handler in your constructor:

```
scrollViewer.Loaded += (sv,event) => ScrollViewerLoaded(sv, event);
```

(or alternately through the XAML)

Save out the state as you have in `SaveState()`. Load the value in `LoadState()` as you have, but instead of using the value immediately cache it until you get to that Loaded event:

```
void ScrollViewerLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs event)
{
    mainScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(cachedScrollPosition);
}
```